# Grab string instances with three characters followed by set of numbers on Mac

Tags: sed, grep

I am trying to grab and keep certain string instances in a text file using Mac Terminal. Some of these string instances happen on the same line, others happen on different lines. Basically, the string instance has the form as follows GO:12345

So, basically, I am trying to grab string instances that begin with the three characters GO: and end with a string of numbers. How can I grab all these string instances in a text file on Mac Terminal? Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
grep -o 'GO:[0-9]*' filename
```

or, if there is a chance that the string `GO:` may occur by itself, and you don't want to see it,

```
grep -E -o 'GO:[0-9]+' filename
```

The `-o` option to `grep` will return the matched strings, not the whole matching line.  If two or more matches occur on a line, these will be returned on separate lines in the output.

The regular expression `GO:[0-9]*` matches the exact string `GO:` followed by zero or more digits, while `GO:[0-9]+` matches at least one digit after the colon (this could also be written `GO:[0-9][0-9]*`).